# Storing chart objects in Array

Tags: vba

I currently want to store a bunch of graphs/chart objects to an array in VBA so I can either print them all out later or export them to a PDF. What is the best way to go about this? Do I have to use the shapes object or can I just do it with charts?

```
    Sub onButtonClick()

Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
Set source = Workbooks("End Market Monitor.xlsm").Worksheets("Aero Graphs")
Set target = Sheet1

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim title_name As String, search As String



search = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
ReDim chartArray(1 To source.ChartObjects.Count) As Chart
For i = 1 To source.ChartObjects.Count
    title_name = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart.ChartTitle.Text
    counter = 1
    If InStr(title_name, search) > 0 Then
        Set chartArray(counter) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next
Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add

    tp = 10

    With wsTemp
        For n = 1 To UBound(chartArray)
            chartArray(n).CopyPicture
            wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            Selection.Top = tp
            Selection.Left = 5
            tp = tp + Selection.Height + 50
        Next
    End With

    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
           IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is possible. What have you tried so far?  What application are you developing in (Excel, PowerPoint, Word, etc.)?

Comment: I am developing in Excel.

Comment: I updated the post. This is what I have so far.

Comment: OK. I'm assuming you're getting an error at the `chartArray(i) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart` line? Are there any other problems?

Comment: Yes. That is it. No other problems that I can think of for now.

Comment: One thing I changed is I went from chartArray(i) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart to chartArray(counter) where counter = 0 and I loop separately because I ultimately want the values starting from index 1 rather than the chart number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of `ActiveCell.Select`. The active cell is *already selected*. It's redundant/unnecessary. Won't cause any errors, but it doesn't need to be there.

There is an error with this line:

```
chartArray(i) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart
```

You need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning to objects, and your `chartArray()` is an array of Objects.

```
Set chartArray(i) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart
```

You should `Dim` all variables on their own line, or explicitly type them. This is wrong:

```
Dim source, target As Worksheet
```

Because VBA doesn't support implicit/in-line declarations. What you've really done is:

```
Dim source as Variant, target as Worksheet
```

Change to:

```
Dim source as Worksheet, target as Worksheet
```

Do the same with `title_name` and `search`.

The variable `name` is undeclared and unassigned. The variable `i` is undeclared. Not an error, but it's a bad habit to get in to. You can avoid this by using `Option Explicit` at the top of each module. You will need to assign `name` some value otherwise the `Instr` test will always be false, and no charts will be assigned to the array.

Your `ReDim` statement is wrong because you're re-dimensioning it within the loop, effectively erasing it every iteration.  Put this *outside* of the for/next loop.

```
ReDim chartArray(1 to source.ChartObjects.Count)
```

Putting it all together, your code should be like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub onButtonClick()

Dim source as Worksheet, target As Worksheet
Set source = Workbooks("End Market Monitor.xlsm").Worksheets("Aero Graphs")
Set target = Sheet1
Dim title_name As String, search As String
Dim name as String

name = "???" '## YOU NEED TO UPDATE THIS SOMEHOW

search = Range("J3").Offset(0, -5).Value

ReDim chartArray(1 To source.ChartObjects.Count) As Chart

For i = 1 To source.ChartObjects.Count
    title_name = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart.ChartTitle.Text

    If InStr(title_name, name) > 0 Then
        Set chartArray(i) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

You can use this procedure for multiple buttons. Currently you had hard-coded `Range("J3")` representing the cell location of the one command button.  You can modify it like this and then assign the same macro to all of the buttons:

```
search = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
```

Make sure that the button's TopLeftCell is in Column F or higher. If this is in column A, B, C, D or E it will fail.

Comment: David, Thank you for the reply. One mistake was that the name was supposed to be the search statement. My bad!

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help you out :)

Comment: David Sorry to bother you again, but I am also trying to copy and paste each of the charts in the array to a separate worksheet and export as pdf. Whenever I run a for loop I still get object defined error with search = activecell.offset. I updated the post with what I have so far.

Comment: probably you should post your new problem as a new question.

Comment: What is the currently *active* cell when you run the macro? If it is in column A, B, C, or D you cannot use an offset of column -5 without raising an error.

Comment: Well, I want the activecell to be where the button is placed. I intend to place a button in each row to reference the (0,-5). I also posted a new question about the PDF exporting.

Comment: the problem isn't the PDF exporting, if it's happening on the `search = ` line. The problem is you're trying to reference a cell that can't or doesn't exist.  **What cell** is this button on?

Comment: How do I define the cell that I put the button on? Isn't that just activecell? Since it's dynamic, I can't just assign it to one particular cell. I need it to offset from the cell the button is placed on.

Comment: What cell is the button on?

Comment: It's currently on Range("J3")

Comment: OK, and what *value* is presently in Cell E3? Is E3 part of a merged cells?

Comment: Nope. I think I can figure this out later. Is it possible that you can help with looping through the array of charts and copy them to a temp worksheet? I looped through but Chartarray(n).copy doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to do this?